# How do I use "format=json&data=" in post requests when developing in python?

Tags: python, json, http, post

```py
format=json&data={
  "pickup_location": {
    "pin": "110096",
    "add": "address",
    "phone": "1111111111",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "country": "India",
    "name": "name of pickup/warehouse location registered with delhivery"
  }
}
```

The data above is the payload of the post required on the API document.

I don't know how to transfer this data because of "format=json&data=".

```py
payload = {
    "pickup_location": {
        "pin": "110096",``
        "add": "Changsha",  # address of warehouse
        "phone": "1111111111",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "country": "India"
    }
}

payload = 'format=json&data={}'.format(payload)
r = requests.post(url_test, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

```py
payload = {
    'format': 'json',
    'data': {
        "pickup_location": {
            "pin": "110096",
            "add": "Changsha",  # address of warehouse
            "phone": "1111111111",
            "state": "Delhi",
           "city": "Delhi",
           "country": "India"
        }
    }
}

payload = 'format=json&data={}'.format(payload)
r = requests.post(url_test, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

These are the two pieces of code I've tried.

The end result is the same: **"format key missing in POST"**.

I also looked it up on the Internet, but I couldn't find the right answer.

So I came to ask for help, 3Q.

Comment: I think you have to fix your format within the json specifically key: 'format', according to the error in the link you provided. POST works by taking in the endpoint, and then the  "/somethingAPI?name='xyz' " which is the body data you're trying to insert in...

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried to request `https://staging-express.delhivery.com/api/cmu/create.json?format=json&data=%7B'pickup_location':%20%7B'pin':%20'110096',%20'add':%20'Changsha',%20'phone':%20'1111111111',%20'state':%20'Delhi',%20'city':%20'Delhi',%20'country':%20'India'%7D%7D`, the result is **"format key missing in POST"**.

Comment: @Peter did you find any solution for this? i'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
payload = {
    "pickup_location": {
        "pin": "110096",
        "add": "Changsha",
        "phone": "1111111111",
        "state": "Delhi",
        "city": "Delhi",
        "country": "India"
    }
}

payload = 'format=json&data={}'.format(payload).replace("'",'"')  # replace is very important
r = requests.post(url_test, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Python strings default to double quotes on the outside and single quotes on the inside. But the api requires double quotes for the parameter key.

Answer (score 2):

I had also same problem actually payload is raw data
so do this

```
payload = {
"pickup_location": {
    "pin": "110096",``
    "add": "Changsha",  # address of warehouse
    "phone": "1111111111",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "city": "Delhi",
    "country": "India"
}
}

payload = f'format=json&data={json.dumps(payload,default=str,indent=4)}'
response=requests.post(url_order,data=payload,headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The format and data key must be sent in body x-www-form-urlencoded type [image: postman]

Answer (score 1):

I was same problem in spring boot .
when i was start searching .
Then i was find this question and i am writing this answer for spring boot developers.

**Packages**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

**Code**

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Token yourToken");
    headers.set("Content-Type","application/json");
    return headers;
}

@Override
public Object save(ExpressDeliveryVO expressDelivery) throws JsonProcessingException {

    HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("format=json&data="+mapper.writeValueAsString(expressDelivery), headers);
    
    return restTemplate
            .postForEntity("https://staging-express.delhivery.com/api/cmu/create.json", entity, Object.class)
            .getBody();

}
```

Comment: Would like to appreciate you friend you made my lot of hard work easier thanks

Answer (score 0):

//This code working fine for me in node fetch

```
const option = {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  Authorization: "Token " + apikey,
  accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: `format=json&data= ${JSON.stringify(createData)}`
```

}